# How to add bearer token to autogenerated OpenApiToCSharpClient?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, nswag

I have client generated using OpenApiToCSharpClient but each request is 401 unauthorized. I have added bearer token in HttpClient like this:

```
ClientEngine.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.Token);
```

and generated client is used like this:

```
 var userClient = new UserClient(HttpClient);
 UserAll.AddRange(await userClient.GetAllAsync());
```

but problem is that auth header isn't added to request (autogenerated code follows):

```
...
request_.Method = new System.Net.Http.HttpMethod("GET");
                request_.Headers.Accept.Add(System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));

PrepareRequest(client_, request_, urlBuilder_);
var url_ = urlBuilder_.ToString();
request_.RequestUri = new System.Uri(url_, System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
PrepareRequest(client_, request_, url_);

var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
var disposeResponse_ = true;
...
```

Request is sent but only the `client_` object has authorization headers but `request_` does not. As far as I know, authorization headers should be also added to request but they aren't. I don't have any property related to authorization in `nswag.json` file - only following properties are related to HttpClient:

```
  "disposeHttpClient": true,
  "injectHttpClient": true,
  "httpClientType": "System.Net.Http.HttpClient",
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything above is correct but apparently, automatic redirection to https was issue - somehow, when request is upgraded from http to https (automatically), it strips the headers. Interestingly enough, Postman didn't have this problem, only `HttpClient`.

Solution - in `Startup.cs`, do this:

```
 if (!env.IsDevelopment())
 {
     app.UseHttpsRedirection();
 }
```